# How to sort results in ascending order on each label in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sorting, label

I have this project that have 2 sets of textboxes ("names" and "time ended" - 3 textboxes for each) and asks to sort the results in a label, showing just the name. How do I do that?

Comment: What you have done already, show us code. Where is exactly your problem !

Comment: @mybirthname

here's the problem:

there are 3 runners, names will be on an input given by the user in the textbox, their finishing time will be on a separate textbox... there are labels marked as 1st place, 2nd, and 3rd... that also have corresponding labels where the names of the person will show up (who gets to be 1st, 2nd, and 3rd)

Comment: show code what have you done so far.

Comment: Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        clear()

        Dim intFinish_Time1, intFinish_Time2, intFinish_Time3 As Integer
        Dim strName_1, strName_2, strName_3 As String

        strName_1 = CStr(txtRunner_1.Text)
        strName_2 = CStr(txtRunner_2.Text)
        strName_3 = CStr(txtRunner_3.Text)
        intFinish_Time1 = CInt(txtFtime_1.Text)
        intFinish_Time2 = CInt(txtFtime_2.Text)
        intFinish_Time3 = CInt(txtFtime_3.Text)

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this...

Comment: I think this will be a FOR LOOP, I just don't know where to start...

Comment: post code in the question not like a comment, in this case more people can help you !